# View click thru

Tags: macos

I have a Mac OS X application.
It has a window when I piled on it some windows. I click on a place which don't accept mouse. The view in the window beneath respond to the mouse. How to avoid that.
Thanks

Comment: This case I use NSTrackingArea with NSTrackingActiveAlways options. I just change it into NSTrackingActiveInKeyWindow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use method hitTest: to check the view is the most far view on the window or not.